# Why SimpleDateFormat is giving different time offsets?

Tags: java, java-7, simpledateformat, timezone-offset

I'm converting few dates from an old format to a newer one. But its output contains different time zones in the formatted string. Sample program :

```
public class Dated {

 private static final DateFormat OLD_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
 private static final DateFormat NEW_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");

 public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
      List<String> list = Arrays.asList(
                "2015-01-18 00:00:00",
                "2016-01-18 00:00:00",
                "2016-03-11 00:00:00",
                "2016-03-13 00:00:00",
                "2016-05-18 00:00:00",
                "2016-05-19 00:00:00",
                "2016-05-20 00:00:00",
                "2016-11-09 00:00:00");

      System.out.println(Locale.getDefault());

      for (String key : list) {
           System.out.println(NEW_FORMAT.format(OLD_FORMAT.parse(key)));
      }
  }
}
```

The same program runs fine in my PC with the correct(and constant) offset of my locale. But when I execute it in a server where the actual application will run, gives the following result:

```
en_US

2015-01-18T00:00:00.000-08:00
2016-01-18T00:00:00.000-08:00
2016-03-11T00:00:00.000-08:00
2016-03-13T00:00:00.000-08:00
2016-05-18T00:00:00.000-07:00
2016-05-19T00:00:00.000-07:00
2016-05-20T00:00:00.000-07:00
2016-11-09T00:00:00.000-08:00
```

I want to know why this happening ? Am I missing something in the code or it's just a buggy implementation of `SimpleDateFormat` ?

NB : I'm not interested in any `Java 8` or `Joda-time` solution.

Comment: What would be the bug here? Is it about the 1 hour difference between summer / winter, probably because of DST?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out so quickly. In fact I live in a country which has no daylight savings hours. So I missed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your timezone applies daylight saving time for the dates in May. It is UTC-8 in the winter months and UTC-7 in the summer.